# How to scan C# project using sonar scanner

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

I am using a sonar scanner on Linux system, and I am scanning the **C#** project. The project is getting scanned successfully but I'm not able to see the  errors of **.CS** files.

I searched regarding this and the only solution I found is scan using MsBuild. So is there only one way to scan C# project using MsBuild or we can scan it without **MsBuild**. And If there is only one way then what is the best practice to use **MsBuild**, also how could I determine the version conflict of using MSBuild.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to build your application somehow. If you are on linux, and you don't have MSBuild, then your only option is to user dotnet global tool: https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-sonarscanner  https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/  Keep in mind, that this apply only to .net core projects.

Comment: @Peska Thank you. Do we need to manage version as well? Do you have any idea how to use a dotnet global tool?